# Coming up with a loop invariant for the partition section Quicksort?

Tags: algorithms

```
void partition(int a[], int L, int R) {
int i = L;
int pivot = a[R];
 for (int j = L; j < R; j++) {
     if (a[j] <= pivot) {
     swap(a[i], a[j]);
      i++;
     }
  }
swap(a[i], a[R]);
}
```

My code is above. My loop invariant is "At the beginning of the iteration, j is in the range of a[L] to a[R-1]". Is this correct? Or if it is not am I on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. What if the elements of `a` were not of the type of `j`/the type necessary to index `a`? Does knowing something about `j` help you in any way: What are you establishing the *loop invariant* for?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of on the right track in that you're trying to relate the *position* of array elements to their *value*, but your statement makes a serious error in directly comparing the value of an index, $j$, to the value of arbitrary data, $a[L]$ and $a[R-1]$.

I think you meant to say $L\leq j\leq R$ is a loop invariant. Observe that $L\leq i\leq j$ is as well, but neither are very interesting statements.

Remember, the motivation for identifying loop invariants is so that we can use them to verify that our code does what it's supposed to. Here, implementing the partition stage of Quicksort, our goal is to rearrange the elements of $a$ such that all the data to the left of the pivot will be less than or equal to the pivot, and all the data to the right of the pivot will be greater than or equal to the pivot.

One important loop invariant is $$\text{For all indices }k \text{ with } L\leq k<i, \text{ we have } a[k]\leq\text{pivot}=a[R]$$
We can see this in your code:

```java
    void partition(int a[], int L, int R) {
    int i = L;
    int pivot = a[R];
    //a[k]<=pivot for all k with L<=k<L=i (true since there are no such k) 
    
     for (int j = L; j < R; j++) {
         //a[k]<=pivot for all k with L<=k<i (inductive hypothesis)
         
         if (a[j] <= pivot) {
             swap(a[i], a[j]);
             //we have now ensured a[i]<=pivot
             //it is an invariant that i<=j  
             //so the elements a[L],...,a[i-1] are unchanged
             //thus a[k]<=pivot for all k with L<=k<i+1
               
             i++; 
             //now a[k]<=pivot for all k with L<=k<i
         }
      }
    swap(a[i], a[R]);
    }
```

Another important loop invariant is $$\text{For all k such that } i\leq k< j, \text{we have } a[k]\geq\text{pivot}=a[R]$$
Again we can see this looking at your code:

```java
    void partition(int a[], int L, int R) {
    int i = L;
    int pivot = a[R];
    
    //a[k]>=pivot for all k with i=L<=k<L=j (true since there are no such k) 
     for (int j = L; j < R; j++) {
         //a[k]>=pivot for all k with i<=k<j (inductive hypothesis)
         
         if (a[j] <= pivot) {
             //it is an invariant that i<=j. now either i<j or i=j
             //if i=j, then there are no k such that i<=k<j, so assume i<j
             //then i<=i<j, and consequently a[i]>=pivot
             
             swap(a[i], a[j]);
             //now a[j]>=pivot and a[i]<=pivot
             //the other elements are unchanged
             //so now a[k]>=pivot for k with i+1<=k<=j
               
             i++; 
             //now a[k]>=pivot for k with i<=k<=j
             
         }
      }//after incrementing j by 1, now a[k]>=pivot for k with i<=k<j
    
    swap(a[i], a[R]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t want “a loop invariant”. You want a loop variant that leads to something you want to prove. Think about what you want after the loop. You want a loop variant that leads bit by bit to your desired outcome.